# How to setup an invisible cron job?

Tags: cron, scheduling

Is there a way to schedule a task using crontab by root user but should not be visible using crontab command i.e, `crontab -l` either for root user or normal users?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what user should the cron job be run as and what user shouldn't be able to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to schedule a task using `cron`, an alternative to `crontab` in many distributions is to add a file to `/etc/cron.d`, in the traditional system `crontab` format (the variant which specifies the user). Tasks defined in this way do not show up in `crontab -l`'s output.

For example, on Debian, `amavisd-new`'s Spamassassin maintenance is scheduled by `/etc/cron.d/amavisd-new`, which contains

```
#
#  SpamAssassin maintenance for amavisd-new
#
# m h dom mon dow user  command
18 */3  * * *   amavis  test -e /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob && /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob sa-sync
24 1  * * *   amavis  test -e /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob && /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob sa-clean
```

Comment: For Example: I have created file with the name hidcron in the location "/etc/cron.d/" with following line added to that file: * * * * * /sbin/ifconfig >> /root/file1. But the given task is not working

Comment: @KarthikVee as mentioned in the answer, you need to specify the user in the task definition, so you'd end up with `* * * * * root /sbin/ifconfig >> /root/file1`.

Answer (score 2):

If your cron job is setup for root user, other users won't be able to see it with `crontab -l` unless they connect as root.

Maybe you can tell us more about what you want to achieve by doing this?